# Change type of reference based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, types, reference

Right now I have roughly this code.

```cpp
Type1 myVarWithAVeryLongName1 = new Type1(); // Really a chain of pointers, but this gets the point across
Type2 myVarWithAVeryLongName2 = new Type2();

template<bool usesType2>
void func() {
    //auto& myVar = usesType2 ? myVarWithAVeryLongName2 : myVarWithAVeryLongName1; // A ternart expression can't return different types
    /*if constexpr (usesType2) {
        auto& myVar = myVarWithAVeryLongName2;
    } else {
        auto& myVar = myVarWithAVeryLongName1;
    } // Puts `myVar` out of scope
    */
    auto& myVar = ?;
    // …
}
```

I want to do a very similar operation on both `myVarWithAVeryLongName1` and `myVarWithAVeryLongName2`. Since the operation takes lots of code and `Type1` and `Type2` are so similar, I can save ~300 lines of code by making one function and resolving the few differences with `if constexpr` blocks. However, the two variables are a lot to type out, so I alias them with `auto& myVar = myVarWithAVeryLongName1;` and use `myVar` for the rest of the function. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not use specialization instead? For common functionality, put it in a separate function with a *type* template, and pass the variable as an argument to it (kind of a proxy pattern).

Comment: Why don't you pass in the variable as an `auto&` parameter, or maybe `auto*` parameter, since your variables are pointers. Your function should not rely on the names of variables outside of the function, unless they are class member variables or (and I really hope they aren't) globals

Comment: `void func(auto& myvar);`  now you can call it on either.

Comment: Benjamin Buch answered my question, but I really don't know why I didn't think of passing in the variable as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an immediately invoked lambda and [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

using Type1 = int;
using Type2 = double;

Type1* myVarWithAVeryLongName1 = new Type1();
Type2* myVarWithAVeryLongName2 = new Type2();

template<bool usesType2>
void func() {
    using type = std::conditional_t<usesType2, Type2, Type1>;
    auto& myVar =
        []() -> type& {
            if constexpr(usesType2) {
                return *myVarWithAVeryLongName2;
            } else {
                return *myVarWithAVeryLongName1;
            }
        }();
    // …
}

int main() {
    func<true>();
    func<false>();
}
```

Comment: Sure, it's not my question though. I also find it oddly phrased and hard to understand.